# If true do something else skip SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Hello, I have data that looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to come with the code that will calculate the 'MERGE' column.
Basically, I should check, if CLM_x >0 then take the value from SZ_x and concat with the value in CLM_x.
I'm trying to use case when, however I don't know how to skip merging if CLM_x =0:
*CASE WHEN CLM_TBL1  > 0 THEN ('Size ' + SZ_1 + '-Qty '+CLM_1) else ... end ...*

Please advise, Thank you!

Comment: Seems like your `CASE` statement is the right way to go here. Any reason that isn't working for you?

Comment: The real struggle here is that your data is not normalized. You are violating 1NF with repeating groups. Any chance you can fix the data structure? If you had properly normalized data this would be a lot less painful....even though the output is not properly normalized either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to string the case statements together.

```
merge = 
    case
        when CLM_1 > 0 then 'Size ' + SZ_1 + '-Qty '+ CLM_1 + ' '
        else ''
    end
    +
    case
        when CLM_2 > 0 then 'Size ' + SZ_2 + '-Qty '+ CLM_2 + ' '
        else ''
    end
    +
    case
        when CLM_3 > 0 then 'Size ' + SZ_3 + '-Qty '+ CLM_3 + ' '
        else ''
    end
```

Answer (score 5):

Yuck.  This is a bunch of string arithmetic:

```
select stuff( ((case when clm1_1 > 0 then concat(', Size ', sz_1, '-Qty ', clm1_1) else '' end) +
               (case when clm1_2 > 0 then concat(', Size ', sz_2, '-Qty ', clm1_2) else '' end) +
               (case when clm1_3 > 0 then concat(', Size ', sz_3, '-Qty ', clm1_3) else '' end)
              ), 1, 2, ''
             ) as merge_column
```